# inline element inside flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Problem :**

I have a flex element and inside of it there´s some text. So far everything was fine, but then someone added a

`<strong>TEXT</strong>`

with our CMS, so the result looked like this:

```css
.flexelement {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexelement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor</strong> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
  dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**Fixed Case :**

I fixed this by wrapping the entire text by an additional text, but I was wondering and searching for a way, that the flexbox ignores the `<strong>`-Element and just arranges it inline with the rest of the text.

Anyone got an idea for this?

Comment: this is how flex works ... the elements become block element

Comment: `Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous sequence of child text runs is wrapped in an anonymous block container flex item.` https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items

Comment: `The display value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent`

Comment: Your text content should definitely be wrapped in p-tags. But what is the function of the flex, you don't seem to need it at all. Post code!

Comment: I need it in my actual project. It´s more complicated there. 
@TemaniAfif Ok, as I thought then. Just was wondering if there was a way to overcome this. Since I fixed this with using a <p> around the flex-item I guess I can close it

Comment: there is no way to overcome this .. you cannot tell flexbox to ignore his job, the only way is to remove `display:flex`

Answer (score 2):

The nature of `display:flex` is to take each and every elements within that element and display as the `flex-flow` is specified.

For example, the following code will take four elements **(before `<b>` tag, inside `<b>` tag, inside `<i>` tag, after `<i>` tag)** to display within the flexbox `.flex-element`

```
<div class="flex-element">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, ratione 
    <b>dignissimos vel laborum animi recusandae porro reprehenderit,</b>
    <i>odio quod at cumque quo esse rem, reiciendis ex consectetur</i> 
    similique dolor voluptatum.
</div>
```

This is due to the browser's default **error tolerance**.

But, in the following example, it will consider only one element **(inside `<p>` tag)** to display within the flexbox.

```
<div class="flex-element">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, ratione 
    <b>dignissimos vel laborum animi recusandae porro reprehenderit,</b>
    <i>odio quod at cumque quo esse rem, reiciendis ex consectetur</i> 
    similique dolor voluptatum.</p>
</div>
```

This is because the whole element is surrounded by a **`<p>` tag**.

Comment: *This is due to the browser's default error tolerance* ? you mean what ... it's simply by design and described within the spec

Comment: same again, thank you :) But I knew this, just wanted to know if there was a way to run around this - thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's the behavior of flexbox, your children elements will be divided in flex boxes automatically.

My suggestion would be to put another parent div for the paragraph, something like this:

```
<div class="flexelement">
  <div>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
     sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
     magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 
     justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
     takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <strong>Lorem 
     ipsum dolor</strong> sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
     diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
     aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 
     justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
     takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: *will be divided in grids automatically.* ? .. and please no link to w3schools, we won't even find any explanation about this

Comment: Thx, this is how i already fixed it. I just wondered if there was another way to tell ignore the <strong> or similar tags